# Dygraphs drawing a vertical line at mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I would like to draw a full height vertical line on a Dygraph plot that follows the precise x position of the cursor (note: I would like it to follow the cursor between points, not just snap to points)

Is there a callback option provided by Dygraphs that would allow this?

As a bonus, is it possible to make it play nicely with synchronisation?

So far I have tried adding a mousemove event listener to the canvas to draw a line on every mousemove event. This ends up just clogging up the plot because I can't clear the previous drawn lines, they just amass with every mousemove event!

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers,

P

edit: I have possibly made some progress. This is hacky but does give the visual effect of a line following the cursor. However, it also overwrites the point highlighting behaviour of Dygraphs. I still need the point highlighting for synchronisation and display of closest point value in the legend.

```
const plot = new Dygraph(...)

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  return [x, y]
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // redraw the plot
  const xrange = plot.xAxisRange();
  plot.updateOptions({dateWindow: xrange});

  // add a line
  const [x, y] =getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
  const { height } = canvas;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [hairlines demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/crosshair.html), which uses the [`Dygraph.Plugins.Crosshair`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/src/extras/crosshair.js) plugin. This tracks the highlighted point using the `select` and `deselect` events and draws a hairline on its own canvas.

It sounds like you're close with the mousemove event. I'm not sure what `canvas` refers to in your example, but it should be one that you create yourself and overlay on the dygraph chart, just like in the Crosshair example. Then you just need to clear the canvas before you draw the line:

```js
  // add a line
  const [x, y] =getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
  const { height, width } = canvas;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
```

You might also be interested in the [hairlines demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/hairlines.html). You can drag the "flags" left and right. They sample from wherever the hairline crosses the curve.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to hairlines, hadn't come across those before. `canvas` refers to  the Dygraph's own canvas but overlaying an identically sized one on top is a far better solution. I did make more progress yesterday by triggering a redraw of the Dygraph canvas with `g.updateOptions({dateWindow: g.xAxisRange()})` but this was starting to impact frame rate and will only worsen as I add more synced plots!

Comment: I went for the overlay method in the end and it works nicely. Have had to add synthetic event generation to clone 'mouseover' events on the Dygraphs div. Have got another question about determining whether a mousemove falls within the plot area of the Dygraph but will open another SO question if I can't find the answer shortly. Cheers, P

Comment: Try setting `pointer-events: none` to make your canvas transparent to events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events or you could make a custom interaction model.

Comment: Ah thanks, I've refactored my code to use that and it's all working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need  to install dygraphs and types/dygraphs
`npm i dygraphs --save
npm i @types/dygraphs --save`

Then you need to insert these lines to work with plugins:

`require('./../../../../node_modules/dygraphs/src/extras/synchronizer.js');`
`declare var Dygraph:any;`

Change the path in the require string according to your project and you can use the plugin while creating the graph. Sample code from my project which is working:

`this.graph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), 
        this.data,
        {
          legend: 'always',
          drawPoints: true,
          animatedZooms: true,
          showRoller: true,
          plugins: [
            new Dygraph['Plugins'].Crosshair({
              direction: "vertical"
            }),
          ]
        })`

I got it working in Angular 8 with Crosshair plugin. You can do the similar in other frameworks.